# How to improve edge detection on IPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, opencv

I'm currently developing an IPhone app that uses edge detection. I took some sample pictures and I noticed that they came out pretty dark in doors. Flash is obviously an option but it usually blinding the camera and miss some edges.

Update: I'm more interested in IPhone tips. If there is a wat to get better pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried playing with contrast and/or brightness? If you increase contrast before doing the edge detection, you should get better results (although it depends on the edge detection algorithm you're using and whether it auto-magically fixes contrast first).

[Histogram equalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) may prove useful here as it should allow you to maintain approximately equal contrast levels between pictures. I'm sure there's an algorithm been implemented in OpenCV to handle it (although I've never used it on iOS, so I can't be sure).

UPDATE: I found [this page](http://opencv-code.com/Histogram_Equalization) on performing Histogram Equalization in OpenCV

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answear. My intention was more toward IPhone dev tips. If none come up I'll also mark this answear as accepted.